# Where do I declare my Angular typed form when the labels depend on properties initialised in the constructor?

Tags: angular-forms, angular14, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I have recently migrated to Angular 14 and I am trying to initialise a Typed Form following [this guide](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-typed-forms/). It is advising to declare the form directly in the class like so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {

   form = this.fb.group({
      email: ["", {
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.email]
      }],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]]
   });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

  }

  login() {

  }
}
```

However, in my case, the form labels depend on a property that is declared in the constructor. As a result, I cannot see my labels on the form. The official guide specifically says: "While trying to leverage typed forms, a very common pitfall that you want to avoid is to declare your form member variables as having the explicit type
FormGroup, like so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

   form:FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      email: ["", {
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.email]
      }],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]]
    });
  }
}
```

... which is what I'm used to doing in that case. How do I make this work?